# How can I implement a 1D CNN in front of my LSTM network

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm, conv-neural-network

At the moment I reshape my X_train like this:

```py
X_train = input.reshape(1,1,12)
```

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100,input_shape=(1, 12)))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(9, activation='sigmoid'))
```

[image: Model image]

But now I am thinking of implementing a 1D CNN in front of this LSTM layer. Does anybody know how this should be done?

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: No, not yet, but I think your answer could be right. I will update when I have solved this issue. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `keras.layers.Conv1D` (see [doc](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/)) that you can applay to your network input.

If you input is of shape `(1,1,12)` and you apply K filters, you'll get an output of shape `(1,1,K)`: so you might want to swap it to `(1,12,1)` to place the steps in 2nd position (check doc).

Note that `model.summary()` might help you debug the input and output shapes of your network.

Comment: But in my case 12 is the number of features. I have 12 time-series signals